# Can't click on content after ajax load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, treeview, devexpress

My problem is this: After downloading content ajax in div element, I can not click on it, or hover mouse, my function is not executed. Please help.

```
var key = null;
var keyProperties = null;
function OnNodeClick(s, e) {
    key = e.node.name;
    //alert('key= '+ key);
    $("#loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Catalogues/UpdateRefInfo",
        cache: false,
        data: { "name": key },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ReferenceObject").load('../Catalogues/test #treeViewInside');
            $("#loading").hide();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }

    });

}
```

And i cant rename my function to `$.("#someclass").on("click")`, because my element DevExpress Treeview, and he has attribute `ClientSideEvent.NodeClick = "OnNodeClick"`.
Please help! How to click and execute function on loaded ajax content?

Answer (score 0):

Its because the elements are dynamic. Say the id of the new div is mynewdiv

then you please change your click event for that div as

```
$(document).on('click','#mynewdiv', function(){
   //do your stuffs    
})
```

Its because dynamic element event will not bind directly without using Live or On
Live is depreciated from 1.8 onwards

Comment: It doesn't Works :(. I can determine #div for each node in my treeview. Can u write full script with changes?